# Azure Function .NET Framework 4.7.2 Unable to load System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.2.0.0

Tags: c#, azure-functions, class-library

I have a solution containing a Azure Function project and a class library.
When I try to use the class library in a function project I get an error

```
Unable to load System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.2.0.0
```

Both projects have the System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.5.4 NuGet package installed.
[Here](https://windows-hexerror.linestarve.com/q/so64864134-unable-to-load-systemthreadingtasksextensions-4200-using-rabbitmq) I found a way to redirect assembly versions. Here is xxx.csproj file of class library project

```
<Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Here is xxxx.csproj of function project (System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions 4.5.4)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AzureFunctions.Autofac" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions" Version="4.5.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

How to fix a problem in a feature project?

Answer (score 1):

- I have  tried to repro the issue with your settings.
- Able to build the application without any errors in the package references, but assembly reference is not loaded correctly for `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`

[image]

- Replaced,

```cs
<Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

***with***

```cs
  <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
```

[image]

Comment: @r00xus do let ,me know if the information provided helped you in solving your problem ?